# PHP+MongoDB: "Return value must be of type MongoDB\Driver\Server, null returned"

Tags: php, mongodb

Exception description:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: MongoDB\select_server(): Return value must be of type MongoDB\Driver\Server, null returned in C:\XXX\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\functions.php:535

Stack trace:
#0 C:\XXX\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Database.php(273): MongoDB\select_server(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager), Array)
#1 C:\XXX\shared\connection.php(6): MongoDB\Database->createCollection('test')
#2 C:\XXX\index.php(11): require_once('C:\\XXX\\...')
#3 {main} thrown in C:\XXX\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\functions.php on line 535
```

I've all drivers installed, configured as well as php module enabled etc.

The code i'm trying to execute:

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb+srv://XXXX/admin?authSource=YYYY&replicaSet=ZZZZ&readPreference=primary&ssl=true');
$collection = $client->CyberNightly;
$a = $collection->createCollection("test");
```

My composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.13",
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "^v3.5.0",
        "ext-mongodb": "*"
    }
    ,
    "require-dev": {
        "roave/security-advisories": "dev-latest"
    }
}
```

Am i making some mistakes? Why this happens? I've generated the connection string using Atlas since it provides you the exact string depending from the version of the driver. (XXX,YYY,ZZZ are to obscure some obv infos).

---

UPDATE:
I also managed to deep dive in the library and found that when i call createCollection method he wants to pass to select_server function the Manager object (Database.php) and for some reason it's empty so obviously it gives problem later on... Also i watched where the libs create that object and the parameters are passed all correctly but after the creation of the object it's empty...

Comment: you did not mention what library is that

Comment: Sorry, i'll add my composer.json to the description

Comment: BTW: I wonder if reporting your problem directly here https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/issues wouldn't be more fruitful for you. It seems they actively maintain the projects, incl. issue reports handling so it (IMHO) would be good to shot there too as maybe you stepped on a bug?

Comment: Like @MarcinOrlowski said, please report this bug in our issue tracked, including the specific version of the MongoDB library you are using.  You can use `composer show mongodb/mongodb` and `php --ri mongodb` to get the appropriate information. Thanks!